# Is it possible to convert tkinter text index to coordinates?

Tags: tkinter, tk-toolkit

I know it is possible to convert coordinate to index in a tkinter `Text` widget. But is the opposite also possible?

Basically I want to find out if the mouse coordinate, while the mouse-button is being pressed, is before or after the coordinate of index `"10.end"` (for example).

Line number can be anything. As mouse is being pressed and not yet released, I can't use `current`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are comparing whether the mouse is over a character before or after another, you don't need to convert an index to a coordinate to do what you want. You can directly compare an index with the x,y coordinates of the event:

```
def on_motion(event):
    event.widget.compare("@%s,%s" % (event.x, event.y), "10.end")
...
text = tk.Text(...)
text.bind("<B1-Motion>", on_motion)
```

If you are trying to compare if the mouse is to the left or right of another character (regardless of the y coordinate), your only choice is to get the x,y of the character and do the compare yourself.

To do that you can use the `bbox` method of the text widget to get the bounding box in pixels of a specific index. You will get back the x/y of the upper left corner of the index, along with the width and the height. You can then compare the `x` coordinate of the event with the `x` coordinate of the index.

Comment: I can't use first method because it doesn't differentiate between `"x.end"` and coordinates after `"x.end"`. `event.widget.compare("@%s,%s" % (event.x, event.y), ">", "10.end")` is 1 for both. Will try using second method.

Comment: @SureshSubedi: I don't understand your comment. What is "x.end"? Your question specifically asks about "10.end". It definitely _does_ differentiate between characters before and after some other character -- that's precisely what it designed to do.  Are you actually wanting to determine if it's to the left or the right of some other x coordinate?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to determine if mouse coordinate is before or after a given index. `compare("%s,%s" % (event.x, event.y), ">", "10.end")` returns 0 even if mouse is after `"10.end"`. I want a method that returns 1 (True) if mouse coordinate is after (to the right of) text index. Comment above contains mistake, method should have returned 0 but I can't edit it anymore.

Comment: @SureshSubedi: ok, so if you're looking for "right of" or "left of" an index, `compare` is the wrong solution. It merely checks if one index is before or after another.