# How to get tkinter text widget coordinates from index

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I’m a newbie in Python and for practice, I’m trying to make a listbox follow my text cursor in a Text widget using tkinter. (The moving listbox will basically serve as a autocomplete tool.) Here’s the closest question to mine: [Is it possible to convert tkinter text index to coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625127/is-it-possible-to-convert-tkinter-text-index-to-coordinates) but unfortunately there’s a better workaround for the thread poster’s problem, so the main question wasn’t answered.

I also tried to use Text.window_create(), which uses index to position windows, but the window/widget is treated like a text and gets deleted if I press backspace/delete. Tried looking into its internal code but I can’t understand :D

Here’s my code:

```
def textChanged(event):
    index = text1.index(tk.INSERT)
    # coord = from index ??
    # list1.place(coord[0],coord[1]
if __name__==‘__main__’:
    root = Tk()
    text1 = Text(root)
    text1.place(x=0,y=0)
    text1.bind(“<KeyRelease>“,textChanged)

    list1 = Listbox(root)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `text1.bbox(tk.INSERT)[:2]` to get the coordinates (relative to `text1`) of the insertion cursor.  However since `list1` is a child of `root` window, it is better to offset this coordinates by the position of `text1` inside `root` window:

```py
def textChanged(event):
    # get the coordinates of text box inside root window
    x0, y0 = text1.winfo_x(), text1.winfo_y()
    # get the coordinates of the insertion cursor inside text box
    x1, y1 = text1.bbox(INSERT)[:2]
    # the coordinates of the insertion cursor relative to root window
    # will be (x0+x1, y0+y1)
    list1.place(x=x0+x1, y=y0+y1)
```